# Jquery toggle content click by class

Tags: jquery

i need a help with jquery; My question is about open and close a li - element with different class by dynamic number. eg.: .open_div.pessoa-1 -> add .d-flex on .pop_experts pessoa-1;

```js
const $jqs = jQuery.noConflict();

$jqs(".link_close").click(function() {
  // It add class bigger to paragraph
  $jqs('.pop_experts').toggleClass('d-none', true);
  $jqs('.pop_experts').toggleClass('d-flex', false);
});

$jqs(".open_div").click(function() {
  // It remove class bigger to paragraph
  $jqs('.pop_experts').removeClass('d-none', true);
  $jqs('.pop_experts').toggleClass('d-flex', true);
});
```

```css
d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div pessoa-1">pessoa-1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div pessoa-2">pessoa-2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div pessoa-3">pessoa-3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="pop_experts pessoa-1 d-flex"><a class="link_close">fechar</a>content by pessoa-1</li>
  <li class="pop_experts pessoa-2 d-none"><a class="link_close">fechar</a>content by pessoa-2</li>
  <li class="pop_experts pessoa-3 d-none"><a class="link_close">fechar</a>content by pessoa-3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear. And the `.open_div` links don't have any text to click on.

Comment: i need show just content by each person. Eg.: when i click on .open_div.pessoa-1 -> open all content by all person on list.. I just need open the content by  .pop_experts.pessoa-1

Answer (score 0):

Put `pessoa-1`, etc. in a data attribute so you can look it up. Then you can use that to refer to the corresponding element in the other list.

```js
const $jqs = jQuery.noConflict();

$jqs(".link_close").click(function() {
  // It add class bigger to paragraph
  let pessoa = $jqs(this).data("pessoa");
  $jqs(`.pop_experts[data-pessoa=${pessoa}]`).toggleClass('d-none', true);
  $jqs('.pop_experts').toggleClass('d-flex', false);
});

$jqs(".open_div").click(function() {
  // It remove class bigger to paragraph
  let pessoa = $jqs(this).data("pessoa");
  $jqs(`.pop_experts[data-pessoa=${pessoa}]`).removeClass('d-none', true);
  $jqs('.pop_experts').toggleClass('d-flex', true);
});
```

```css
d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div" data-pessoa="1"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div" data-pessoa="2"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div" data-pessoa="3"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div" data-pessoa="4"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="open_div" data-pessoa="5"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="pop_experts d-flex" data-pessoa="1"><a class="link_close">fechar</a></li>
  <li class="pop_experts d-none" data-pessoa="2"><a class="link_close">fechar</a></li>
  <li class="pop_experts d-none" data-pessoa="3"><a class="link_close">fechar</a></li>
  <li class="pop_experts d-none" data-pessoa="4"><a class="link_close">fechar</a></li>
  <li class="pop_experts d-none" data-pessoa="5"><a class="link_close">fechar</a></li>
</ul>
```